# How to check if List contains several elements in order

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Let's say I have a List,

```
Arrays.asList("A","B","C","D");
```

Is there a convenience method in Java that allows me to check this List to see if the elements C and D are on this list in that order?

Something along the lines of:

```
Collections.containsOrderedElements(list,"C","D");
Collections.containsOrderedElements(list,"A","B","C");
```

Where the above methods will return true but

```
Collections.containsOrderedElements(list,"A","C");
```

will not?

Comment: Will the List always be sorted or can it be unsorted also?

Comment: Nope.  No such method exists in core Java.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a method in the `java.util` package that can help (`Collections.indexOfSubList(sourceList, subList)`):

```java
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
System.out.println(Collections.indexOfSubList(list, Arrays.asList("C", "D")) >= 0);
System.out.println(Collections.indexOfSubList(list, Arrays.asList("A","B","C")) >= 0);
System.out.println(Collections.indexOfSubList(list, Arrays.asList("A", "C")) >= 0);
```

It prints:

```
true
true
false
```